# Protractor: Jenkins won't build project locally (mac)

Tags: jenkins, protractor, automated-tests

As I'm trying to run a sample jenkins project from my machine.  However, I it won't build my project locally.

I outline the set up [in this jing video](https://www.screencast.com/t/VArHVEG64rQJ)

What did I do wrong?
What specific steps should I use to fix it.

Error message from jenkins

```
Started by user Jacqueline George
Building in workspace /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.jenkins/$(JENKINS_HOME)/LocatorTraining
[LocatorTraining] $ cmd /c call /var/folders/2s/d8lh31wd3_7dx65htqzvpcv80000gn/T/jenkins6260102670441278278.bat
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.jenkins/$(JENKINS_HOME)/LocatorTraining"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:935)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:454)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1819)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Build configuration**

[image]

How I am executing the build

[image]

**Code after using npm run protractor in shell**

```
Started by user Jacqueline George
Building in workspace /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.jenkins/$(JENKINS_HOME)/LocatorTraining
[LocatorTraining] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/2s/d8lh31wd3_7dx65htqzvpcv80000gn/T/jenkins563599888073808645.sh
+ npm run protractor
npm ERR! path /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.jenkins/$(JENKINS_HOME)/LocatorTraining/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.jenkins/$(JENKINS_HOME)/LocatorTraining/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.npm/_logs/2018-11-13T10_38_04_562Z-debug.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I made a modification to the build.  I selected 'shell' (as I'm a mac user) not windows batch (as my tutor instructed).  I also removed customer workspace from my configuration

Added the following command in 'build'

> /Users/JacquelineGeorge/Documents/Jenkins/LocatorTraining&&npm run
>   protractor

It still failed but this message was at least different.

I also tried this with and without `${JENKINS_HOME}` under

> General>Advanced>use custom workspace

```
Building in workspace /Users/jacquelinegeorge/.jenkins/workspace/Protractor
[Protractor] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/2s/d8lh31wd3_7dx65htqzvpcv80000gn/T/jenkins8556486662152409824.sh
+ /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/Jenkins/LocatorTraining
/var/folders/2s/d8lh31wd3_7dx65htqzvpcv80000gn/T/jenkins8556486662152409824.sh: line 2: /Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/Jenkins/LocatorTraining: is a directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You missed the `cd` at the head of command. It should be `cd /Users/JacquelineGeorge/Documents/Jenkins/LocatorTraining && npm run protractor`

Answer (score 2):

The failure is due to you choose build step of `Execute window batch command`. But your Jenkins slave machine (where your test script resides) is a linux.

You should choose `Execute shell` for that build step.

Comment: Thank you for taking a minute to answer my question.  I still can't get it to run. This is what I did [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/3DnmtRUs)

Comment: Please show your jenkins  job configuration by screenshot in your question. You can edit your question and add that screenshots.  Also add the jenkins build log after you change to `Execute linux shell`

Comment: At `Use Custom workspace` section, change `$(JENKINS_HOME)` to `${JENKINS_HOME}`.  In jenkins, using pattern `${Vriable_Name}` to reference Environment Variable

Comment: Seems your `JENKINS_HOME` is point to folder `/Users/jacquelinegeorge/.jenkins`, please confirm the folder `LocatorTraining` is under there.

Comment: My tutor my project is pointed there I was instructed to do so by my tutor.  Is that a problem

Comment: Did you commit your code into Source Code Management Tool, like Github or put them on the Jenkins master where the Jenkins web application deployed on?

Comment: No I'm just trying to build my project locally from my machine.

Comment: Where is the jenkins master?  If you use your machine as jenkins master, you are no need to config `use custom workspace` and you can put your script folder anywhere you want.  For example you put your script folder under `/Users/jacquelinegeorge/workspace/projectA`, then you can use shell as following in `Execute shell` textbox:  `cd /Users/jacquelinegeorge/workspace/projectA && npm run protractor`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  I made the changes.  Build failed but its was a different message.  I think we are making progress

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to to do a summary of this conversation.

1. From your project page select `configure`
2. Scroll down to `build`
3. Under build select `shell`
4. enter `cd /Users/YourUserNameHere/YourProjectWorkSpace/ProjectFolder/FileName&&npm run protractor`
5. `Save`

When you click build now.  Your project should now build locally from your machine.